# SSAS, how to make Dimension Attribute Month only show the months in current year?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

In our date dimension, there are Month and Year attributes. Month attribute has set int month_year as key, to avoid duplicate problem, and Month attribute has name like January, February...

Now there is problem, if user drags Year and Month to filter, and would define one year, say 2017, he expect to see Month Attribute in filter only shows 12 month names in 2017. However, Month Attributes shows month names for all years, the names repeating many times.

There is already calendar hierarchy built in this dimension. But the user wants to define filter outside of hierarchy. How to build such Month Attribute in cube? Does some one have any idea about it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved. Just add a new column in date table, say Month_in_current_Year, has the same content as Month column. Add this new column to date dimension as a new attribute. This new attribute works for my purpose. It shows only 12 elements as months in one year. And it slices correct value while setting it to filter. What magic is the cube!